# Find $\Vert f \Vert$ for a functional $f$ over $C[-1,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let , $\displaystyle f:C[-1,1]\to C[-1,1]$ be defined by $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{-1}^0 x(t)\,dt -\int_0^1x(t)\,dt$. Find $\Vert f\Vert$ with respect to sup norm defined on $C[-1,1]$.

Firstly , $\displaystyle |f(x)|\le \int_{-1}^0\sup_{-1\le t\le 1}|x(t)|\,dt+\int_0^1 \sup_{_1\le t\le 1}|x(t)|\,dt=2\Vert x\Vert$.

Then we get , $\Vert f\Vert \le 2$.

I couldn't find the reverse inequalty. I'm unable to construct $\Vert f\Vert \ge 2$.

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739461/finding-the-bound-of-a-linear-functional-defined-on-c-1-1) but that answer is not clear to me.

Comment: Try to construct a function $x$ with$ \|x\| \le 1$ to make $f(x) = 2$.  Or (since $x$ has to be continuous) nearly $2$.

Comment: Your answer depends on you define the norm $||\cdot||$ on the space ${\cal C}[-1, 1]$.

Comment: I just edit the question. Defind norm is **sup norm**.

Comment: This not a map from $C[-1,1]$ to $C[-1,1].$

Comment: See also:
[Norm of the operator $Tf=\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt-\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/317861),
[Finding the bound of a linear functional defined on $C[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1739461),
[find linear functional norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1182293),
[Finding the bound of a linear functional defined on $C[-1,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1739461).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence of functions

$$x_n(t) = \left\{ \begin{array} 
.1 & \forall t \in [-1,-\frac{1}{n}] \\
- nt & \forall t \in [-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}] \\
-1 & \forall t \in [\frac{1}{n},1] 
\end{array} \right.$$

The $x_n$ are continuous, $\|x_n\| = 1$, and $f(x_n) \to 2$ when $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 1):

Another example: Let $x_n(t) = t^{1/(2n+1)}, n = 1,2,\dots $ Then $\|f_n\|= 1$ for every $n,$ while

$$f(x_n) = \frac{2}{1+ 1/(2n+1)} \to 2.$$