# Integral Inequality calculating operator norm

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

I was looking at this problem: [Norm of the operator $Tf=\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt-\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317861/norm-of-the-operator-tf-int-10ft-dt-int-01ft-dt) and was confused about the step with the integral inequality:

$$\left|\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt-\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt\right|\\ \leq \int_{-1}^0|f(t)|\ dt+\int_{0}^1|f(t)|\ dt\\$$

Is there a rule for this inequality that I'm missing? In the first equation, if it was addition, I could use the triangle inequality. Here, is it using the assumption that the sum would be greater than the difference?

Comment: $|\int f| \le \int |f|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you can see the first equation as an addition:

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt-\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt\right|&=\left|\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt+\left(-\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt\right)\right|\\\\
&\leq \left|\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt\right|+\left|-\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt\right|\\\\
&= \left|\int_{-1}^0f(t)\ dt\right|+\left|\int_{0}^1f(t)\ dt\right|\\ \\
&\leq \int_{-1}^0|f(t)|\ dt+\int_{0}^1|f(t)|\ dt\\\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed the first part of adding the negative and then it all falls into place.